# WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 111

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

Why am I getting the following error? `WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 111`, so returning the closest version found: 109?

In my pom.xml file I have the following dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumAutomationAssertions</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumAutomationAssertions</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Chrome version is up to date (Version 111.0.5563.64)

Following is the code which I'm trying to execute:

```
package testcases;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Verify.Compare;

public class ValidateElementExistsByXpath {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    boolean result;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void createDriver()
    
    {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/imtiyaz/Documents/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Allow essential and optional cookies']")).click();

        
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    
        
        
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testcase3()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Hello");
        Compare.ValidateElementExists(driver, "//input[@id='pass']"); //This is the xpath which will be checked, will return either true or  false, so I'll set 'boolean result' above
        Assert.assertTrue(result); //I'm expecting that the element should exist, hence using assertTrue
        
    
    }
    

}
```

I initially added `selenium-http-jdk-client` in pom.xml and using `System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");` within my code and also updated my chrome version as well as the selenium-java version in pom.xml file and selenium-http-jdk-client to 4.8.0

Answer (score 2):

According to selenium `v4.8.0` changelog, below is the supported CDP versions:
[image]

Reference link: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

You chrome is on version `111`. This incompatibility in the versions is the reason for warning on your console.

**Solution:**

- If you need this warning to disappear, you need to downgrade the chrome version to `109`
- Having said that, I don't think this warning will cause you any issues while running your code. You can ignore the warning and proceed with it.

Comment: Thanks! So I need to downgrade my Chrome version then?

Comment: Yes you can downgrade it to 109. However, I think you can just ignore this warning. Your code will work just fine(I think).