# WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 111

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vps

I was able to start up correctly on a vps chrome driver however it gives me these warnings... can you help me?

```
$ java -jar demo.jar

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 25982
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Mar 22, 2023 8:27:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 111
Mar 22, 2023 8:27:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for .
You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.8.1` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.

Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 4625
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Mar 22, 2023 8:27:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 111
Mar 22, 2023 8:27:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for .
You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to
`org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.8.1` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Thanks to whoever will answer and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Check this link, if it answers your query - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75775660/7598774

Comment: Hi @Shawn , Yes maybe that's what I was looking for, so I have to downgrade the version of Google Chrome and Chrome driver?
Or do you advise me to leave it like this as it won't bother the code?

Comment: According to this guide, does my version ( changelog v4.8.1) support up to 110? (I have the 111) [link]:(https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG)

Comment: Yes v4.8.1 supports 110 as per the official change log. You can downgrade if you wish to. As I have suggested in the link, its a warning and can be ignored. Its the warning which is displayed due to incompatibility. Your code will run just fine. However am not very sure that it may not have any other hidden adverse effects.